# TypeError: _appStoreServerLibrary.SignedDataVerifier is not a constructor node js app-store-server-library

Tags: ios, node.js, server, in-app-purchase

while verify signed data with app-store-server-library.
facing while crating base object TypeError: _appStoreServerLibrary.SignedDataVerifier is not a constructor

fin out on documentation form github repo and github documentation.
https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-node?tab=readme-ov-file
https://apple.github.io/app-store-server-library-node/classes/SignedDataVerifier.html#verifyAndDecodeTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SignedJWTVerifier` from `app-store-server-library`

for example

```js
import { SignedJWTVerifier } from 'app-store-server-library';

const verifier = new SignedJWTVerifier(appleRootCAs, enableOnlineChecks, environment, storeConfigs.appStore.BundleId, appAppleId);
```